# "Tried to read unmapped address" error in Gem5 SE simulation

Tags: gem5

Why do I encounter this error ? Will it stop appearing if I do a full system simulation ? Or is there any way I can map the whole DRAM for simulation ?

I am trying to simulate PARSEC benchmark applications on Gem5, these are binaries for x86 ISA.

On another note; why does this message keep appearing ?:
warn: DRAM device capacity (8192 Mbytes) does not match the address range assigned (512 Mbytes)

I have a total RAM of 12GB, so it makes no sense (8+4)

Edit: The application when ran on its own (on my system) has no issues or errors

Edit2: Tried running FS simulation; the simulations doesnt stop, I let it run for ~5 minutes.

Edit3: The issue with SE seemed to be because of the hooks Parsec has now; I compiled the code without the hooks and it seems to work for simpler ones.

But now I have another problem:
But some applications (canneal, facesim for example) keeps on running without exiting the simulation; from their outputs (to see the output I run the simulation without any debug flags), they seem to reach the region of interest but then the simulation keeps running. Is it just the simulation taking an absurdly long time ?

Edit4: The simulations kept running because of the input sizes, which I had set for large (simlarge inputs in Parsec); so yes, they were running for an absurdly long time. I ran them afterwards with small input sizes to the applications and have had reasonable simulation times.

Comment: Please provide the source for the binary you used and or try to debug further, e.g. with `--debug-flags SyscallBase` and `--debug-flags ExecAll`, or GDB on the guest program to determine exactly what instruction caused. FS is generally more robust.

Comment: The binaries I am using is from PARSEC benchmark suite, compiled for x86. I tried running with debug flags, but the simulation does not stop !!

Comment: Also is there any way I can know how to get the telnet commands for the FS simulation ?

Comment: 1) So the simulation behavior is different with and without debug flags? If so it is likely a serious / hard to debug  C++ undefined behavior bug. 2) telnet: do yo mean how to connect to the simulation? Use the `m5term` executable present in gem5, `telnet` does not work properly. Automated in [this setup](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/928f9b84accb47aba54ada44e2ea3f587dd3b9f9#gem5-buildroot-setup-getting-started) via `./gem5-shell`.

Comment: Using m5term:
Kernel panic - not syncing: No init found.  Try passing init= option to kernel.

Comment: You have to pass a valid image / init combination to gem5. You could copy what [this working setup is doing](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/811b04c3f858fc24d681617d88b65ae8836fd808#gem5-buildroot-setup).

Comment: I have used the X86 images from : http://www.m5sim.org/Download

Comment: @CiroSantilli I have added an edit to the question; Can you please address that ??

Comment: sorry, but I'm not sure :-) I would try to run it on the host computer to see how long it takes to try and estimate how long it should take. I would then try to see if there is a parameter to control the problem size, I remember parsec had big and small inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seemed to be caused by the Parsec Hooks; I edited them out from the config/make files and the simulations ran without issues.

Other issues I met while trying to run the simulation and the "solutions" have been added as edits.